# Ctrl + K + D - The style sheet contains syntax errors and cannot be formatted

Tags: visual-studio, css, visual-studio-2010, code-formatting

In Visual Studio, when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to format code, I'm getting this error

[image: The style sheet contains syntax errors and cannot be formatted]

As per the [suggestion](http://forums.asp.net/post/4082304.aspx), I've tried to solve the issue:

- In Visual Studio, open the Tools menu and select Options
- Expand the Text Editor group, then the CSS group.
- Click on Miscellaneous and you'll see the option to enable Detect Errors there.

[image: Detect errors is enabled]

The code I need to format is:

```
.ie .actual-form table {
width: 100%
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you try using an online beautifier to check, that you really don't have any syntax errors? You can use other offline editors with the corresponding plugins instead, if you don't feel like putting your code on an online tool.

Comment: Again: other tools or applications format just fine without any syntax errors? Which version of Visual Studio are we talking about?

Comment: @Seika85 Yes, they do well

Comment: The error tab is not showing any errors whatsoever? (Which version of Visual Studio?)

Comment: You could try to paste your full CSS (not only the alleged culprit part you posted) to a validation tool (e.g. https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input) and replace your original CS with the validated one? Maybe some illegal characters made there way in there.

Comment: It's VS10 only. The entire code is getting formatted correctly.